# Elapsed Time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small piece of code that I want to accomplish 3 things on:

1. User Enters Birthday
2. User is able to see current date
3. When user clicks button, they are given the time elapsed between their birthday and now (i.e. current time - birthday).

The trouble I am having is that when the button is clicked all I get is NaN. I am not sure how to proceed at this point.

```
        <li><label>Enter Your Birthday</label></li>
        <li><input type="date" name="field1" id="field1"></li>

        <li><label for="date">Current Date</label></li>
        <script id="curDate">
            var d = new Date();
            document.write(d);
            var bDay = new Date(document.quiz.field1);
            var eTime = d - bDay;
            function calcDate(eTime) {
                document.write(eTime);
            }
        </script>
        <li><input type="button" value="Click" onclick="calcDate(eTime)"></li>
```

Comment: `new Date(document.quiz.field1)`  <-- `field1` is the input. So you are trying to convert the input to a number, not its value

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks for linking, this is very helpful!

Comment: @epascarello that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById('field1').value` to get the value of the `input` and pass that in to `new Date` to create a date object. You can then get the difference between that and today to get the elapsed time.

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value));
```

Comment: To improve your answer, please [edit] your answer to add a bit of explanation how this works, and why this is the best solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @WilliamJuan thank you, this makes more sense now. I will format it for give me years months days etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a lot of bugs - Try this (I only upgrade your code to work - it still looks ugly):

```
<li><label>Enter Your Birthday</label></li>
<li><input type="date" name="field1" class="field1"></li>
<li><label for="date">Current Date</label></li>
<li><span class="dateCalc">x</span></li>
<li><input type="button" value="Click" onclick="calcDate()"></li>

<script >
  var d = new Date();
  document.write(d);

  window.calcDate = function calcDate() // we bind to window.calcDate for fiddle
  {
    var bDay = new Date(document.querySelector(".field1").value);
    var eTime = d - bDay; // diffrence in miliseconds (can be mins if birth date is from future)

    document.querySelector(".dateCalc").innerHTML = eTime+ ' [ms]';
  }
</script>
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p9gaq6tu/3/).

Comment: I should clarify that I am trying to create functionality. What are the bugs you mentioned, could you clarify?

Comment: @LilyV. Of course:  1. wrong way of reading `bDay` (not work), 2. read `bDay` and `eTime` calc in wrong place-time (should be after click- so inside function), 3. write result in wrong way (`document.write`  delete whole page), 4 function `calcDate` should not have argument. 5. You manipulate html doc in wrog way e.g. `document.write(d)`. 6 js code mixed with html. Additionaly in my opinion the value of `eTime = d - bDay`  is right becouse you not precise what time format you wanna get (so you have in [ms]) and we don't need to take absolute value of it (in case of distinct future dates)